# how can we add SVG icons to create the ribbon

Tags: excel, visual-studio, svg, icons, ribbonx

Can we add SVG icons instead of PNG icons using custom UI Editor? if not then how can we add SVG icons in Visual Studio (I'm using VB NET language to create the ribbon)

I tried adding the SVG icon in custom UI editor but it gives me the prompt "Parameter not supported!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following formats of icons for Ribbon controls:  bmp, png and ico. Vector graphics (SVG) is not supported.

You need to convert your SVG file into one of the supported file formats. The `ico` images can embed images with different resolutions, so the MS Office may pick up the most appropriate one.

Comment: Thanks, now that I am creating modules in VS using VB.NET, is there a way to refer to the microsoft's library of icons? the way we use imageMso in customUI editor

Comment: Found it, Instance I add a button in the ribbon > Properties > Appearance > OfficeImageID. The image id of the microsoft built in library of icons can be input here.